# RegEx to remove CR/Newline after specific tag

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following input and want to remove every /newline that comes after the regex matches the Paragraph tag.
Input:

```
<head> \n
<P class="someclass"> \n  (I will remove onle these ones)
Need to get this line.. \
```

Output:

```
<head> \n
<P class="someclass">Need to get this line.. \n
```

So what I want do to is to remove the ones that match  /n and remove the newline.
How could I do that?

Or alternatively how could i capture the line after the /n as it is this line I need to read?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12880699/what-c-sharp-regular-expression-would-extract-the-following-content

Comment: I do not have the possibility to add another library... If I just do it in sublime I could do <P.*> \n to find every occurences, and the just remove the \n. But do not know how to do it with code..

Comment: Do you have this html as string in some variable? you can even use String.Replace("/n",String.Empty)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you mean `/n` as new line character `\n`?

Use the following Regex/code, which also considers `\r` and `\r\n` as new line:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

string result = Regex.Replace(
    value, 
    @"(\<p[^\>]+\>)(\r|\n)+", 
    "$1", 
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: Is there  possible to use a Regex.Match(input) to instead of removing the \n to capture the next lines value? Where the Regex is the @"(\<p[^\>]+\>)(\r|\n)+"

Comment: Consider changing the `+` in `[^\>]+` to match a `<p>`

Comment: Well, nevermind. The above worked as a charm, just replaced the input first and then did my match. Great!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
var result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(input, "<[p|P](.*)> /n", "<p$1>")
```